# mapping with data from axios call using async await in react

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

I am able to get data back from my api call. But when I try to map it, I get an images.map is not a function. I consoled log the data to make sure it is an array

Here is my code

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import DisplayData from "./DisplayData";

function Home() {
    const [images, setImages] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        const getApi = async () => {
            const tempData =  await axios.get(
                "https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/rovers/curiosity/photos?sol=10&api_key="
            );
            setImages(tempData.data.photos);
            console.log(tempData.data.photos);
            console.log(images);
            // // console.log(typeof( images));
            images.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element);
            });
        };
        getApi()
    }, []);

    if (!images) {
        return <h1>Waiting</h1>;
    } else {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Home</h1>

                {images.map((item) => (
                    <DisplayData key={images.id} images={images} />
                ))}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Home;
```

Comment: Are you sure that images is really an array and not maybe an array inside an object?

Comment: First - change your `const [images, setImages] = useState({});` to `const [images, setImages] = useState([]);`. Second - setImages does not update `images` immediately, so `console.log(images);` just after `set` will not write down new values

Comment: ^ yep, and a solution for this is to write another `useEffect` with dependency on `images` and do your `forEach` there (if you indeed want to do something after it changed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you initialize the `images` variable as an object. Objects do not have `map` method on their prototype and are also not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

If you want it to not throw an error, initialize as an array (which does have the `map` function) or as a [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value in order for the first if to be executed and be in the waiting state.

```js
const [images, setImages] = useState(null); // or useState([])
```